# Bash Tarball script exiting with failure

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tar

Can anyone tell me why the following script is failing?  I can't figure it out.

```
#!/bin/bash

D="$(date +%V).tar.bz2"
E="$(date +%V).tar"
P="mnt/Xendata/Weekly/"

tar cjvf $P"dbtime_week_"$D --newer="1 weeks ago" mnt/DBTime

tar cjvf $P"pounds_week_"$D --newer="1 weeks ago" mnt/Pounds

tar cjvf $P"fts_week_"$D --newer="1 weeks ago" mnt/FTS/DB\ Backups

tar cjvf $P"projects_week_"$D --newer="1 weeks ago" mnt/Projects

tar czvf $P"groups_week_"$E --newer="1 weeks ago" --ignore-case --exclude=*Expo*Films* --exclude=*/Promo\ Material/* mnt/Groups

tar czvf $P"users_week_"$E --newer="1 weeks ago" --ignore-case \
--exclude=*cache* \
--exclude=*dvdproj* \
--exclude=*iDVD* \
--exclude=*IMAP* \
--exclude=*Temporary.localized* \
--exclude=*.app* \
--exclude=*Spotlight* \
--exclude=*iTunes* \
--exclude=*/Library/PubSub* \
--exclude=*/Downloads/* \
--exclude=*.mpg \
--exclude=*.mov \
--exclude=*.mp4 \
--exclude=*.m4v \
--exclude=*/dev/* \
--exclude=*ladmin* \
--exclude=*/widgets/* \
mnt/Users

exit $?
```

This is the output.  Most of it goes through, but then it fails:

```
tar: mnt/Groups/~$xxxxxx.xls: file is unchanged; not dumped
tar: Option --after-date: Treating date `1 weeks ago' as 2012-07-19 17:29:42.104908153
tar:  : Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
tarball_weekly: line 25: --exclude=*Spotlight*: command not found
tarball_weekly: line 29: --exclude=*.mpg: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure that there is no character after the backslashes at the end of lines :

```
cat -ve tarball_weekly
```

to see if there are ^M characters for example (format dos) before $ (end of line)

Comment: There was a single whitespace at the end of the preceding line.  Thanks!